# Node Buffer.prototype.toString returns incomplete string

Tags: javascript, node.js, csv, base64, buffer

Trying to parse a csv in node using a `Buffer` but the return value seems to be incomplete:

Code:

```
app.post('/upload/import', function(req, res) {

    var base64str = req.body // which returns data:text/csv;base64,VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRoaW5nDTQxMDIxMjE4NzINOTA5ODc2MTI0NQ0yOTIxMjc
    var data = base64str.substring(base64str.indexOf(',') + 1, base64str.length); \\ remove 'data:text/csv;base64,
    var encoded = new Buffer(data, 'base64').toString('ascii');
    console.log(encoded); // returns '2910387473thing'

});
```

When I run this exact base64 string through a base64 service I get this result:

```
This is a thing
4102121872
9098761245
2921278901
9981223489
6482034847
3948820123
8483920383
3849201837
2910387473
```

The base64 string is `VGhpcyBpcyBhIHRoaW5nDTQxMDIxMjE4NzINOTA5ODc2MTI0NQ0yOTIxMjc4OTAxDTk5ODEyMjM0ODkNNjQ4MjAzNDg0Nw0zOTQ4ODIwMTIzDTg0ODM5MjAzODMNMzg0OTIwMTgzNw0yOTEwMzg3NDcz`

This is the site where I've verified my base64 is correct: https://www.base64decode.org/

What is happening to truncate my data?

Comment: Are you using Express for your routing or something else? And whether it's Express or something else, do you know what version?

Comment: @Trott Yes, express, 4.10.4. I'm also using connect-csv to retrieve the csv data to req.body.

Comment: @bencripps i think it's issue with connect-csv, because it was not updated to connect 4.x.x, where was some break-through changes.

Comment: Update: I removed connect-csv and simply add `text/csv` as an allowed type to `body-parser` -- I get the exact same result, the same base64 that gets truncated. I decided to simply serve the result as `text/plain` and split on comma.